# Simple probability question with normal distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A,B$ are random variables that are normally distributed around zero, what is $P(A+B \ge 0)$?

My thought is $P(A+B \ge 0) = P(A \ge -b | b \ge 0) P(b \ge 0)+P(A \ge -b | b \le 0) P(b \le 0)$. Let $ P(A \ge -b | b \ge 0) = x$ so then $ P(A \ge -b | b \le 0) = 1- x$. Thus $P(A+B \ge 0) = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}(1-x)=\frac{1}{2}$. This makes intuitive sense. However, if you then consider $P( A+ B \ge 0 | B \ge 0) = \frac{P(A+B \ge 0)}{P(B \ge 0)} = \frac{1/2}{1/2} = 1$. This doesnt make sense....

Please help?!

Answer (score 1):

To assume that $A$ and $B$ are centered normal does not yield the distribution of $A+B$, which could even be non gaussian. If $A$ and $B$ are centered normal **and independent**, then $A+B$ is centered normal hence $P[A+B\geqslant0]=\frac12$.

Comment: Yes they are independent. If that probablity is $\frac{1}{2} $, then $P( A+ B \ge 0 | B \ge 0) = \frac{P(A+B \ge 0)}{P(B \ge 0)} = \frac{1/2}{1/2} = 1$? This doesnt make sense since this cant possibly occur with probability zero since theres a possibility that $A$ is negative and its magnitude is greater than that of $B$.

Comment: Actually, $P(A+B\geqslant0\mid B\geqslant0)$ is $P(A+B\geqslant0,B\geqslant0)/P(B\geqslant0)$, that is, $2P(A+B\geqslant0,B\geqslant0)$, not what you wrote.

Comment: And if $A+B$ is independent from $B$ then this is $1/2$ but if they are not independent can this probability still be determined?

Comment: Sure. But this is a different question hence you should ask another question.